# Are these two correct? Do they sound okay?

Tags: sentence-construction

Q1. "He **deserves** his success."
I guess this sentence sounds correct. Am I right?

Q2. "His success **is** not **deserved**."
What about this one? Is it correct?

Comment: 'Deserve' is a transitive verb so its passive can be made. Second one is correct too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:)